# MYSQL insert array variables in php creates duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I made a simple script that inserts data into my table from an array named $videos.
The result is that I get a table with correct titles but the ID is repeated over and over in all rows that were inserted. 
The strange thing is that when I echo $id inside the loop I get the correct id's each time. for some reason it does not insert to the table the correct id's too.

This is my code:

```
     $page_counter = 0;
do{
    $videos = $bc->find("allVideos",array("page_number" => $page_counter,"page_size" => 10, "media_delivery" => "http"));    
    for ($movie_counter = 0; $movie_counter < count($videos); $movie_counter++){
       $name = $mysqli->escape_string($videos[$movie_counter]->name);
       $id = $videos[$movie_counter]->id;
       echo "ID " . $id . "<BR>";
       $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO bc_current2(id,title) VALUES('$id','$name')");


    }
    $page_counter++;
}
while (count($videos) == 10);
```

So for example if each time I get printed ID's: 1 , 2 , 3 ,4 ...
In my table I see the same ID : 1 repeated in each row but the title is correct and not repeated.

Comment: $videos[$movie_counter]->id; is probably a double indexed array

Comment: POST a print_r of $videos[$movie_counter] outside any loop and post it in your qeustion.

Comment: I tried print_r($videos[$movie_counter]) after the last while... I get no result in this case

Comment: `$movies_counter` is created within the previous block, so it doesnt exist under the last while xD. `print_r($videos[$movie_counter])` or `var_dump($videos[$movie_counter])` on the place you `echo` it now, and make sure to do it either for just 1 movie, or that you keep track of what is posted when.

Comment: This is how my for loop looks now:    for ($movie_counter = 0; $movie_counter < count($videos); $movie_counter++){
       $name = $mysqli->escape_string($videos[$movie_counter]->name);
       $id = $videos[$movie_counter]->id;
       var_dump($videos[$movie_counter]);

Comment: In this case I get a full var_dump of the objects... Starting like this: object(stdClass)#4 (22) { ["id"]=> int(2053114464001) ["name"]=> string(21) ....

Comment: Ok... I managed to fix the problem... It seems like my ID field in my database was int and it was not sufficent. I changed it do bigint and not it works.